# How to use spark structured streaming to simultaneously write to parquet and call REST API

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, avro, parquet, spark-structured-streaming

How to use spark structured streaming to simultaneously write to parquet and call REST API? Below is where I need to integrate with:

1. Through spark SQL structured streaming, am able to consume from Kafka Topics.
2. The message is in avro format, and able to write into parquet filesystem.
3. On the other hand able to read the parquet filesystem and fire any SQL query as per the need.

Below are few integration or processing I am stuck, can anyone please help:

1. So, I have to now integrate a rest call, simultaneously I should be able to write to parquet filesystem and call the rest API.
2. To call rest API I should also convert the Dataset to Avro object first and then prepare the request object for REST API.

The above streaming implementation is done on JAVA. Preferably if JAVA based API or approach is suggested that would be great help.

FYI. I am using the latest version of spark streaming:
spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.12 -> 2.4.0
spark-streaming_2.12 -> 3.0.1

```
{
//dataSet -> dataset having kafka message
Dataset<Row> output = dataSet.select(package$.MODULE$.from_avro(col("value"), avroSchema).as("EventMessage")).select("EventMessage.*");

output
    .writeStream()
    .outputMode(OutputMode.Append().toString()).format("console")
    .foreachBatch((VoidFunction2<Dataset<Row>, Long>) (df, batchId) -> {
        df.write().mode(OutputMode.Append().toString()).format("parquet").partitionBy("action").parquet(STREAM_PARQUET_OUTPUT_PATH);
        // REST API CALL BLOCK
        //df -> avro object -> API Rquest Object -> REST Call
        
     }).start().awaitTermination();
}
```

Comment: What does your code look like so far? Have you tried using forEachBatch with a REST Client?

Comment: Thank you for your showing interest here. I was trying that option but unable to do the transformation, also I would loose the parquet write trigger option since the message in foreachBatch will be dealing with with single message at a time:

Comment: '//dataSet -> dataset having kafka message
Dataset<Row> output = dataSet.select(package$.MODULE$.from_avro(col("value"), avroSchema).as("EventMessage")).select("EventMessage.*");

output
 .writeStream()
 .outputMode(OutputMode.Append().toString()).format("console")
 .foreachBatch((VoidFunction2<Dataset<Row>, Long>) (df, batchId) -> {
  df.write().mode(OutputMode.Append().toString()).format("parquet").partitionBy("action").parquet(STREAM_PARQUET_OUTPUT_PATH);
  // REST API CALL BLOCK
  //df -> avro object -> API Rquest Object -> REST Call
  
  }).start().awaitTermination();'

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the code

Comment: @OneCricketeer added code

Comment: So, you dont need "df to avro object". Rather you would go straight to the API object. You would indeed need to loop over individual rows of the dataset, then do your api call. Alternatively, you could write to a new Kafka topic with the dataformat you expect, then consume off that topic for the API requests, or if you can edit the API code, embed a Kafka consumer to it

Comment: @OneCricketeer the 1st option looks fine but was thinking is there way we can work with list of stream directly because parquet write one record at a time wont be efficient.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding. `df.write().parquet(path)` on its own takes that entire dataframe to the filesystem. You need a second line, separately that does loop over `df` there, or at the very least `df.map` into request objects

Comment: Thank you @OneCricketeer was little away. Yes you are correct, and able to get this working. Thanks once again.

Comment: Nice. Feel free to show your solution below as an answer